# Optimize Pagination with SQL

Tags: mysql

What is the best practice for optimizing pagination with mySQL? SQL query is something likes

```
Select * from SOME_TABLE where id <= SOME_NUMBERS and OTHER_OPTIONAL_CONDITIONS_TO_FILTER_RESULTS order by id desc limit NUM_RESULTS_PER_PAGE
```

My current method is to cache the first few pages, but normally the process of invalidating cache results is quite complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an offset to `LIMIT`, so the query returns only the contents of the page you are looking for. For example, considering each page has 20 records:

```
-- Page 1
SELECT * 
FROM some_table
LIMIT 0, 20

-- Page 2
SELECT * 
FROM some_table
LIMIT 20, 20

-- and so on...
```